# MSI error: requires administrative rights

Tags: wix, windows-installer, admin-rights

It works on Win7 when I run msi file from local disk and from network share.

But when I run msi file on Win8-10 I get an error:

> This application requires administrative rights

I set for Product:

```
 InstallScope="perMachine"
 InstallPrivileges="elevated"
```

Also, I have 10 custom actions (.NET).

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running it from elevated command prompt?

Open Start, type "cmd", right click on "cmd.exe", click "Run as administrator". Then navigate to your MSI file and use msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi"

If you want your installer to start elevated itself, you can create a bootstrapper application (executable file) to run it.

Comment: Yes, I have my own Setup.exe app + manifest, it runs msi and all works ok. It is interesting: I have another msi, it works ok without bootsrtappers. As I see the difference between them in Custom actions. May be CA is a reason that msi(1) does not run?

Comment: If I run cmd as Administrator then this "msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi"" works ok, else the same error. (win10)

Comment: But are you sure that your Setup.exe is running elevated? If your "another msi" runs fine, it could mean that your installer does not require administrative privileges.

Comment: Well if msiexec runs fine, it means that your Setup.exe is not requesting the admin permissions.

Comment: If I run cmd as Administrator then this "msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi"" or I run my Setup.exe - in these cases works ok,  if I run cmd (not as administrator) and "msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi"" or I run directly msi file - then error.

Comment: I just didn't understand what is that you were trying to achieve. I though you just wanted to run the MSI. If you want to know the reason, then yes, the cause might be the CA.
If you want to force the MSI itself to be elevated, there is only one hackish way, which is described [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Custom-Actions-with-elevated-privledges-td5435239.html)

Comment: Yes, right, I create this MSI and want to know the reason and to fix it if possible.

Comment: On your link Rob Mensching wrote: "That's why you need a bootstrapper. " It means it it does not make sense to try to fix anything in msi itself. Thanks